# useEffect won't update code in webview automatically in React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, react-navigation, use-effect

I use a stack navigation from reactnavigation. When opening Screen X I want to automatically update "let userAnswer = "";" with a string within a webview. However, the code won't run. It does run and updates the variable when I save my file in visual studio.

I make the code run via useEffect. This is the webview in my WebViewComponent:

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import DarkModeContext from "../store/darkmode";

const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
    <script>
        function update() {
            var idoc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
            idoc.open();
            idoc.write(editor.getValue());
            idoc.close();
        }

let userAnswer = "";
```

Here is the useEffect that is supposed to run in WebViewComponent:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    webref.injectJavaScript(props.defaultContent);
console.log("mounted")
  },[]);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "65%", marginTop: 0 }}>
        <WebView
          ref={(r) => (webref = r)}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true} // To prevent crash when opening screen
          scalesPageToFit={false}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          source={{ html }}
        />
      </View>
```

I get default content prop from the screen I am using the wWebViewComponent in:

```
<WebViewComponent
  defaultContent = {`userAnswer += "Hello World"
  editor.setValue(userAnswer, 1);
    `}
/>
```

It acts as if the component doesn't mount when navigating to it via reactnavigation, though this is of course not the case. The console.log does return "mounted". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put as a dependency the `defaultContent `, and  `webref.injectJavaScript`?

Comment: Hey - thank you for the answer. webview and webref.injectJavascript already are dependencies in my screen component that I access via reactnavigation. :-/

Comment: @FotiosTsakiris I edit the question to hopefully shed some more light on the issue :-) For further clarification: the useEffect does return the console.log, it is only the webview that is not updated :-/

Comment: I found a solution. Instead of using useEffect I added `injectedJavaScript={props.defaultContent}` to webview to show my default content.